# Creating many relationships with calculated properties

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j and I'm having fun with some data about our solar system in a game (called Elite Dangerous). As a trader, you want to find the most profitable route based on certain criteria. One of them is the number of jumps needed between on system and another. To calculate that, we first need to calculate the distance between  all systems within 30Ly for every system so I've devised this query to calculate the distance in question :

```
MATCH (s1:System), (s2:System)
WITH s1, s2, (sqrt((s2.x-s1.x)^2+(s2.y-s1.y)^2+(s2.z-s1.z)^2)) AS dist
WHERE dist < 30 AND dist > 0
CREATE UNIQUE (s1)-[:IS_DISTANCED_FROM {distance: dist}]-(s2)
RETURN count(dist)
```

A system as x,y,z coordinates. The query is so slow, even after some hour, it didn't finished. Am I doing something wrong?

I've an index on System and i'm using version 2.1.6.

My cypher query failed but my database is at 806 777 relationship now. Is there a way to clean it because the relationships doesn't appear when I query for them afterward.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with a subset of your systems, to see where the execution plan is taking the most time.

Can you run this query in the neo4j shell and post the result of the Exectution ? :

```
PROFILE MATCH (s1:System)
WITH s1
LIMIT 15
MATCH (s2:System)
WHERE s2 <> s1
WITH s1, s2, (sqrt((s2.x-s1.x)^2+(s2.y-s1.y)^2+(s2.z-s1.z)^2)) AS dist
WHERE dist < 30 AND dist > 0
CREATE UNIQUE (s1)-[:IS_DISTANCED_FROM {distance: dist}]-(s2)
RETURN count(dist)
```

Comment: I ran the command (without PROFILE because it didn`t work) and here is the result :
count(dist)
1740
Set 1716 properties, created 1716 relationships, returned 1 row in 4816 ms

Comment: By my calculation, for the whole 19800 systems, it should take 110 minutes overall but after 2-3 hours, it didn't complete :(

Comment: it did not work because you did not ran it in the shell

Comment: I cannot post the result in a comment, it's too long :( Any suggestions? Also, would it be better to create a collection of systems and use a FOREACH statement to calculate the desired distance?
Also, do you know how to push Neo4j to use 100% CPU instead of 40%?
Thanks for your help again!

Comment: a github gist would be fine

Comment: Would it be faster this way ? :
`MATCH (s1:System), (s2:System)
WITH s1, s2, (sqrt((s2.x-s1.x)^2+(s2.y-s1.y)^2+(s2.z-s1.z)^2)) AS dist, tail(collect(s1)) as coll 
WHERE dist < 30 AND dist > 0
FOREACH (x in coll | 
  CREATE UNIQUE (s1)-[:IS_DISTANCED_FROM {distance: dist}]-(s2)
)
RETURN count(dist)`

Comment: would you mine providing a subset of your data?

Comment: I'm not sure your query will perform better, the best way I see now is to work with two systems collections and unwind, but it is hard to say without data right now, I just need to generate some.

Comment: Here is the csv file I used : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By7CiFQVf4LSOS1yb0x1cmlzU2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And the Cypher :
`USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/systems.csv" AS line
MERGE (s:System {name: line.SystemName })
ON CREATE SET s.x = toFloat(line.SystemX), s.y = toFloat(line.SystemY), s.z = toFloat(line.SystemZ)
ON MATCH SET s.x = toFloat(line.SystemX), s.y = toFloat(line.SystemY), s.z = toFloat(line.SystemZ)
RETURN count(s)`

Comment: Just to let you know I have been very busy, I tried some queries but can't get good results without limiting and skipping the set, I'll post a gist here soon.

Comment: Thanks for your help, very appreciated! I'm curious about the unwind command you talked about. I felt, reading the doc, that it would be the command to use but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not surprising that your query takes a long time, since it has complexity O(N*N). And indexing does not help, since you are not matching using specific property values.

I would recommend that you calculate the distances programmatically *outside* of Cypher, and then use Cypher just to create the relationships. This will still be slow, but probably much faster than trying to do everything within Cypher.

Also, you can halve the number of calculations you need to perform by noticing that [the distance from System A to System B] equals [the distance from System B to System A]. You only need to create a single distance relationship between any 2 Systems.

Finally, to identify the apparently spurious relationships in your DB, you can try something like this query to take a look at some of them:

```
MATCH ()-[r]->()
RETURN r
LIMIT 50
```

If you are REALLY REALLY CERTAIN that you want to get rid of ALL relationships, you can use the following query. To be safe, you may want to first make a backup copy of your DB (shut down the DB server, make a recursive copy of its `data/graph.db/` folder, and then restart the server).

```
MATCH ()-[r]->()
DELETE r
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I use Cypher query, the relationships doesn't exist (MATCH ()-[r::IS_DISTANCED_FROM]->()) but in the neo4j Dashboard, there is 809 517 relationships now...I'm pretty sure 600 000+ of those shoudn't exist. Anyway I can flush the cache of the DB?

Comment: How could I create a single distance relationship between 2 systems? I thought the the CREATE UNIQUE served this purpose?

Comment: You should not qualify your query with a relationship type. That is, use `[r]` instead of `[r:IS_DISTANCED_FROM]`. Your DB apparently has a lot of relationships of other type(s).

Comment: All relationships are directional. When you Create using the `(a)-[r]-(b)` syntax, you are actually creating a directional relationship starting at `a` and ending at `b`. Ideally, you should use `(a)-[r]->(b)` instead, to make this clear. So, what I am saying in my answer is that you do not need to calculate and create a relationship in the opposite direction (i.e., from `b` to `a`).

Comment: When I count all relationships in my DB (because I have other relationships), MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN count(r) count(r) = 91056. Here I found in the comment on the Dashboard the explanation :
A note on primitive counts
The number of nodes, properties and relations are estimates based on file sizes. Actually counting the nodes is not done for performance reasons. These are usually very accurate, but in certain cases if you have experienced a database crash and subsequent recovery, they may be very wrong.